# How can I get data from map in array?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase screenshot is as below. But I don't know how can I access my datas in array.

Comment: For instance `var d = theMap['begendikleri'][0]['postId']`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to access whole datas in array. I want to create a list to show liked posts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this code

```
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/PClEKWNc1fG8zo0OWgHs');
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await docRef.get();
if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
  List begendikleri = documentSnapshot.get('begendikleri');
  print(begendikleri);
  print(begendikleri[0]);
  // you can then loop through begendikleri and do stuffs
}
```

Comment: So glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you can use like this:

final posts = data['begendikleri'].map((e) => Post.fromJson(e)).toList();

where `data` is the snapshot returned by the firebase, and Post is an object with the properties of the post.

The fromJson function can be like

```
factory fromJson(Json) {
return Post(postId: json['postId'], saticId: json['saticId']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Single access `var d = theMap['begendikleri'][0]['postId']`

You can also iterate the array and create the list you want simply

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: theMap['begendikleri'].length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
    'The id if the post is ${theMap['begendikleri'][index]['postId']}',
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm a new developer at firebase so I don't know what does it mean 'theMap'. What should I write instead of theMap?

Comment: Your actual data returned from firebase, aka `snapshot.data`

Comment: Thanks again for your comments but I still don't understand what you mean. What should I do?

Comment: Since you lack the basic implementation, I would strongly suggest looking the docs here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage they are well written, and all your answers will be answered.

Answer (score 2):

try using this site :

https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

this will generate a dart class to parse your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

```
    final Map<String,dynamic> documentSnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.collections("Users").doc("REPLACE_WITH_DOCID").get()

documentSnapshot["begendikleri"]; // gets list of your maps in begendikleri
documentSnapshot["begendikleri"][index]; // gets map data from list with gived index(0,1,2,3,4...documentSnapshot["begendikleri"].length)
documentSnapshot["begendikleri"][0]["postId"]; // gets postId value from first element in begendikleri list from DocumentSnapshot
```